# nodejs get request after post ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I have big problem to use AJAX...
I don't want anything after ajax, but GET 304 page after success ajax...
here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/crawling/list",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            // ifModified: true,
            async: false,
            data: {
                'query': input
            },
            success: (data) => {
                    ...
            },
            fail: () => {
                ...
            }
        })
```

during about 0.00001 milisecond posted page is loaded and back to original get page..... my nodejs express console like this
[my express console...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfo4I.jpg)

What's the problem? TT

Comment: I don't understand what the question/problem is here.

Comment: Sorry I can't write english very well...

Comment: umm I request POST using ajax, and successfully get data but after get data, 304 GET request appear... and change /crawling/search page origianlly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find HTML button element issue!
If I don't select button type, page should reload page.
If I use 
there is no reload.
Good Good